# Como selecionar todas as tabelas no mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, query

Qual a query que me faz consultar um determinado banco no mysql que me traga todas as suas tabelas?

Comment: Sim é possível!

Comment: show tables ...

Comment: mas como? um amigo meu disse que tinha que informar o schema... mas não consegui encontrar

Comment: caramba... show tables funcionou... rs

Comment: Não entendi o downvote ...

Comment: nem eu, deixa pra lá

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mysql> USE test;
Database changed
mysql> SHOW TABLES;

+----------------+
| Tables_in_test |
+----------------+
| t1             |
| t2             |
| t3             |
+----------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

acredito que seja isso que está pedindo, está um pouco ampla.

Comment: é o comando mais simples das soluções apresentadas!

Answer (score 3):

Você pode usar o `show tables` para esta finalidade, veja um exemplo:

```
show tables from
minhaBaseDeDados;
```

Ele aceita a clausula `from`, e com ela você pode especificar o seu banco de dados.

Fonte:http://imasters.com.br/artigo/3001/mysql/comando-show/

Comment: ajudou e muito, não usei o from, como já tava na base usei apenas "show tables"

Answer (score 1):

Pode fazer isso no MySQL, através do [information_schema](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-schema.html) que guarda os meta dados dos banco de dados.

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'database'
```

Comment: os outros comandos são mais simples, mas essa sua solução traz mais detalhes

Comment: @DiChrist sim vc pode outras informações ai depende da sua necessidade.